# what to use for instant messaging capabilities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, message-channel

I am appearing for the microsoft exam 70-486. While going through the dumps I came across the below question

You are developing an ASP.NET MVC application that provides instant messaging capabilities to customers.

You have the following requirements:

1. Messages must be able to be sent and received simultaneously.
2. Latency and unnecessary header data must be eliminated.
3. The application must comply with HTML5 standards.

You need to design the application to meet the requirements.
What should you do?

A. Configure polling from the browser.

B. Implement long-running HTTP requests.

C. Implement WebSockets protocol on the client and the server.

D. Instantiate a MessageChannel object on the client.

Now I am confused between C and D options. On the web, most of the people are saying C is the answer but as far as I know it won't satisfy the 1st requirement
"Messages must be able to be sent and received simultaneously".

Any help would be appreciable .
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Coming from previous experience building instant messaging functionality into a social network web app. Here are some technologies to look at:

- [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) (For communication between the server and client)
- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (Page layout and styling, with HTML5 compliance)
- [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) (Ease of use when handling requests, and displaying messages)

Try building a small test application and work out for yourself which technologies work well.

Comment: Hi @Alex, Thank you for the response. Actually, I needed to get the answer to  the above question because it was in the dumps and could have come in the exam. I am done with my exam and didn't get this question. If I will need to work on instant mesaging functionality I will create small applications and test as you suggested.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer would be Option D

Comment: Can you please add reason for your answer.